# Paste multiple columns (strange behaviour)

Tags: r

I'm trying to paste several columns with the same name each into a new row but I get some strange behaviour. Example:

```
x <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y= 2:11, z= 11:20)
colnames(x) <- c("x", "y", "x")
x
> x
    x  y  x
1   1  2 11
2   2  3 12
3   3  4 13
4   4  5 14
5   5  6 15
6   6  7 16
7   7  8 17
8   8  9 18
9   9 10 19
10 10 11 20
# now I try to paste columns to rows 

> x2 <- data.frame(columns = unique(colnames(x)), 
+                  values = sapply(1:length(unique(colnames(x))), function(i)
+                    paste(x[,(which(unique(colnames(x))[i]==colnames(x)))], collapse = ", ")))
> x2
  columns                         values
1       x                    1:10, 11:20
2       y 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11
```

What I wanted to have is just

```
> x2
columns                         values
1       x 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20
2       y 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11
```

Could somebody help me preventing this behaviour?

Comment: As a note, there is no need to call `unique(colnames(x))` so many times; you could save in a variable instead. Also, if you don't need this task for a specific formatting, you might consider avoiding coercing to "character" and `paste`ing -- `aggregate(cbind(values = unlist(x, use.names = FALSE)) ~ rep(names(x), each = nrow(x)), FUN = c)`. Finally, you are passing a "list" of "integer"s (columns named "x") to `paste` which, implicitly, uses `as.character` on this "list" and the result is because of how `as.character` treats "list" arguments -- `as.character(list(1:5))`

Comment: Thanks that was a really helpful explanation! I use paste since my real data is actually text but it still makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
x <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y= 2:11, z= 11:20)
colnames(x) <- c("x", "y", "x")
unique_cols <- unique(colnames(x))
x2 <- sapply(unique_cols, function(s) unlist(x[, unique_cols == s], use.names = F))
x2

$x
[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
$y
[1]  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11
```

and

```
typeof(x2)
[1] "list"
```

in case you need a dataframe with the collapsed values:

```
df <- data.frame(columns = unique_cols,
                 value = as.character(sapply(x2, function(s) paste(s, collapse = ","), USE.NAMES = F)))

df

  columns                                              value
1       x 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20
2       y                              2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11
```

Comment: Worked like a charm :)